# Window in wpf does not grows and changes location

Tags: wpf, animation, window

I am new to WPF.
I try to change the size and the location of the window while it is opened.
but it does not work. only the 3 out of 4 properties grow ( the top 3 in the order of writing).
Attached code :

```
<Window x:Class="Client.X64.TestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Client.X64"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TestWindow" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" x:Name="Test" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent">
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard x:Name="WindowMoveSB">
                    <DoubleAnimation x:Name="AnimationMoveWindowLeft" Duration="0:0:5.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Left)" Storyboard.TargetName="Test" From="20" To="200"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation x:Name="AnimationMoveWindowTop" Duration="0:0:5.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Top)" Storyboard.TargetName="Test" From="20" To="200"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation x:Name="AnimationMoveWindowHeight" Duration="0:0:5.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Storyboard.TargetName="Test" From="20" To="400"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation x:Name="AnimationMoveWindowWidth" Duration="0:0:5.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Storyboard.TargetName="Test" From="20" To="400"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid x:Name="TestGrid" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrushKey}}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MouseRightButtonDown="TestGrid_MouseRightButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonDown="TestGrid_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I would appriciate a responce
Shlomy

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by "it does not work". I've just copied your code into a test project and it seems to work for me.

Comment: In TestGrid_MouseLeftButtonDown Event add this.DragMove(); for allowing user to drag your window.

Comment: @tabby the above code moves and grows the window after it's first loaded. It can then be moved by the user as normal. The issue is that there is something wrong with that movement but the OP hasn't defined exactly what that is.